# Spring Cloud Config Compilation failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I cloned Spring Cloud Config from Github (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config) and it comes with spring-cloud-build version 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, however it does not compile (cannot resolve boot.Banner, boot.context and boot.env in NativeEnvironmentRepository.java).

I read around and decided to try 1.0.2.RELEASE as found on http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/ but it still does not compile (still cant resolve boot.env etc). I tried changing Spring Cloud to version Angel.SR3 but that didn't make any difference.

I am using Mac OS X El Capitan and Maven 3.3

Has anyone else had this issue? I also tried it on Windows 7 and on my EC2 instance.

Update: the server & client ran for a few executions on the CLI using `code`mvn spring-boot:run`code` but eventually the compile errors returned

Comment: The stuff you're mentioning sounds more like a runtime exceptions, not compilation problems. Please include the error stack traces directly into your question by editing it.

Comment: I was getting compilation errors and IntelliJ was highlighting various classes as unresolved (see below). However I managed to get the server partially started on the CLI.


COMPILATION ERROR:
[ERROR] server/environment/NativeEnvironmentRepository.java:[27,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Mode
  location: interface org.springframework.boot.Banner

[ERROR] server/environment/PassthruEnvironmentRepository.java:[63,38] no suitable constructor found for Environment()
    constructor org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment.Environment() is not applicable

Comment: Server starts on CLI but errors when I run spring-cloud-config-client:

codeorg.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.] with root cause org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactorycode

Comment: You can't 'run' `spring-cloud-config-client`. It's a client library. Also you should be using `./mvnw.bat` to build.

Comment: thanks spencergibb yes I am using mvnw, although I have been using  ../mvnw as the spring docs say `code`cd spring-cloud-config-server`code`